# Windbg undo the zap

Tags: windbg

My application is running in loop, it encountered an Assert. To avoid the assert each time in the loop I did a zap by `EB address 90`

Now I do not know how to undo the zap and debug the Assert ?

Comment: There is no undo functionality, so remember the value and do a `EB address rememberedvalue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no undo functionality for that. So you have to remember the value(s) and undo the operation by yourself, e.g.

```
eb <address> <remembered value>
```

WinDbg has a *Scratch Pad* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>) where I write down notes like this. If you right click the window, it will even write into a file. I prefer this over Notepad++ since it can be docked into WinDbg's main window. You can even save the Scratch Pad as part of a workspace.